# Mapping values and keys from a nested dictionary to columns

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I am working with the following dictionary

```py
store_dict = {'store1': {'itemA' : 1},
              'store2': {'itemB' : 2},
              'store3': {'itemC' : 3}}
```

My ultimate goal is to map the values (i.e. the nested dictionary) into seperate columns of a dataframe. So I want to turn this dataframe

```py
    store

0  store1
1  store2
2  store3
3  store1
```

to the following dataframe.

```py
    store   item   price

0  store1  itemA       1
1  store2  itemB       2
2  store3  itemC       3
3  store1  itemA       1
```

I did `df['store'].map(store_dict)` and some regex twice to make the item and price columns, but now I am more interested in knowing if there is a way to directly get the keys and values of the nested dictionary into columns. Throughout my research on working with nested dictionaries to get the price, we have to use `store_dict['store1']['item1']`  which will not scale for the size of data and I am still not too sure how I would go about to only get the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> store_dict = {'store1': {'itemA' : 1},
              'store2': {'itemB' : 2},
              'store3': {'itemC' : 3}}
>>> temp_df = pd.DataFrame(store_dict)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'store':temp_df.columns, 'item':temp_df.index, 'price':temp_df.sum(axis = 1)})
>>> df = df.append(df.iloc[0])
>>> df.reset_index()
    store   item  price
0  store1  itemA    1.0
1  store2  itemB    2.0
2  store3  itemC    3.0
3  store1  itemA    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
store_dict = {'store1': {'itemA' : 1},
              'store2': {'itemB' : 2},
              'store3': {'itemC' : 3}}
df = pd.concat({        k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, 'index') for k, v in store_dict.items() }, 
    axis=0).reset_index()
df.columns =  ['store', 'item', 'price']
df
```

Output:

```
    store   item    price
0   store1  itemA   1
1   store2  itemB   2
2   store3  itemC   3
```